# Safely granting permission to a Perl script to change users and groups of filed downloaded with rsync

Tags: permissions, scripting, rsync, perl

I've got a Perl script which is a wrapper to a `Net::OpenSSH` object which I use to `rsync` a remote server's files to my local machine. I'm using the archive, `-a`, option to preserve file ownership and permission. When I download the files, however, the user and owner is set to my local user and group, not the user and group of the files on the server.

I changed the group of my script to `admin` which can run all commands with no password. But this didn't work.

Is there a way to do this securely without having to enter a password?

Comment: You're basically asking how to grant the script super user privileges without asking for a password? Running the script using sudo would do that. If that is secure or not depends on the script and the user using it.

Comment: You can do part of what you're asking with sudo. You can limit a user to being able to only use the command useradd. However your problem is probably bigger. Linux doesn't by default use ACLs and it just uses a user id and group id that is not random ids are just created in order. This means this id is likely to map from the old systems first user to the new systems first user and so on.

Comment: The problem is if I run as sudo, it won't be able to find my locally installed perl library.

Comment: @StevieD Run sudo with the -E option.

Comment: Thanks but still got perl errors with `-E`. It can't find the necessary modules.